# Failure to register the value in the database (laravel 8 ,Bootstrap 5 )

Tags: laravel, bootstrap5-modal

I proceeded to register the child comment through the following method, but unfortunately the amount of the child comment is not stored in the database

Comment form

```xml
@auth
    <div class="modal fade mt-5" id="sendComment">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ارسال نظر</h5>
                </div>
                <form action="{{ route('send.comment') }}" method="post" id="sendCommentForm">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="commentable_id" value="{{ $course->id }}" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="commentable_type" value="{{ get_class($course) }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="0">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">پیام دیدگاه:</label>
                            <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">لغو</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ارسال نظر</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endauth
```

comment blade

```xml
@foreach($comments as $comment )
    <div class="box shadow mt-3 mb-3">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="commenter d-flex">
                <img src="{{ $comment->user->getProfileUrl() }}"  class="circle"  height="50">
                <span class="text-muted" style="margin-right: 10px;margin-left:10px;">{{ $comment->user->name }}</span>
                <span class="text-muted">  - {{ jdate($comment->created_at)->ago() }} مطرح شد</span>
            </div>
            @auth
                <span class="reply" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#sendComment" data-id="{{ $comment->id }}">
                    پاسخ <i class="fas fa-reply"></i>
                </span>
            @endauth
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-dark">
            {{ $comment->comment }}
            @include('layouts.comments' , [ 'comments' => $comment->child ])
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

js

And this problem is only in Bootstrap 5 and in Bootstrap 4 it works properly with this jQuery code, please help me how to solve this problem

```js
<script>
    // $('#sendComment').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    //     var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    //     let parent_id = button.data('id');
    //     var modal = $(this)
    //     modal.find('input[name="parent_id"]').val(parent_id)
    // });
    
    var myModal = document.getElementById('sendComment')
    var parent_id = button.data('id');
    var myInput = document.getElementByName('parent_id').parent_id;
    myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        myInput.focus()
    })
</script>
```

How should I write jQuery code in Bootstrap 5?

Comment: Did you check whether this is a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Yes, it works properly in Laravel 8 and Bootstrap 4 versions , But in version 5 of Bootstrap this is a problem

Comment: "This is a problem" - what does that mean? What exactly is not working as expected? Also, if this is a problem of Bootstrap, please share the generated markup

Comment: I do not know exactly

Answer (score 0):

Your code should still be the same. The event's `.relatedTarget` should return the button.

To set an input's value, you use `.value`. Focusing a hidden input does nothing. You should focus the textarea instead.

```js
var myModal = document.getElementById('sendComment')

myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', event => {
    const button = event.relatedTarget;
    const parent_id = button.data('id');

    const hiddenInput = document.getElementByName('parent_id');
    hiddenInput.value = parent_id;

    const textarea = document.getElementByName('comment');
    textarea.focus();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the same as before and the comment is not registered as a child and the comment is considered separate